# Is running makemessages necessary every time?

Tags: django, locale, po

I'm reading the django documentation for `makemessages` but the wording is not very clear:

> Runs over the entire source tree of the current directory and pulls out all strings marked for translation. It creates (or updates) a message file in the conf/locale (in the Django tree) or locale (for project and application) directory. After making changes to the messages files you need to compile them with compilemessages for use with the builtin gettext support.

In the text above it doesn't seem clear to me what it means that `makemessages` would "pull out" strings marked for translation. (pull them out for what? where to?)

Meanwhile the `compilemessages` description makes sense as this simply compiles the messages once I've changed the language files.

When, if ever, should I use `makemessages` if `compilemessages` does the job I am seeking? What is the point of `makemessages`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`makemessages` is used to scan through your apps looking for strings marked for translation. Once it has theses strings it puts them in a `po` file. If you then add further strings for translating to your app then you will need to run `makemessages` to generate an updated `po` file. `compilemessages` uses the contents of the `po` file to create a `mo` file, so the `po` file must be updated first.

`makemessages` accepts a param for the locale:

```
pipenv run django-admin makemessages --locale=de
```

This allows you to create a `po` file for each of the locales your app supports.

Comment: Thanks @Stu. I see that running `makemessages` also keeps removing strings from my po file. Really frustrating. I think I can only add strings to ta po file by letting `makemessages` automatically extract them from a html file somewhere?